# How to check multiple ranges for different values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to search 3 different ranges in a tab, and trying to display Yes if all three values (email address, name, x) are found in those ranges. Basically, trying to have the formula confirm that yes, all three of those inputs are somewhere in those ranges (order doesn't matter).

Maybe I should use query or regexmatch or something? Any help is appreciated

Tried this formula:

=IF(AND('Helper Calculations'!$I:$I=$A$1,'Helper Calculations'!$J:$J=L$1,'Helper Calculations'!$L:$L=$A2),"Yes","No")

Was expecting that if the search term in each of those cells ($A$1, L$1, $A2) is found somewhere in the corresponding ranges, then it would say Yes

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this (you can change the use of asterisks by wrapping in AND:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Helper Calculations'!$I:$I,$A$1)*COUNTIF('Helper Calculations'!$J:$J,L$1)*COUNTIF('Helper Calculations'!$L:$L=$A2),"YES,"NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(('Helper Calculations'!I:I=A1)*
          ('Helper Calculations'!J:J=L1)*
          ('Helper Calculations'!L:L=A2), "Yes", "No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Took a bit more work than I expected, but I got this working. I needed to verify that all 3 values were correct in a single row (must all be correct on that one row, can't find the correct values on multiple rows).
In order to do that, I needed to use array formula, and then decided to use index match and concatenate for the 3 values.
Process described here: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/google-sheets-index-match/

correct formula: =IF(ArrayFormula(INDEX('Helper Calculations'!$I:$I,MATCH(CONCATENATE($A$1,L$1,$A2),'Helper Calculations'!$I:$I&'Helper Calculations'!$J:$J&'Helper Calculations'!$L:$L, 0),))=$A$1,"Y"))